# Not able to email registeration confirmation email

Tags: php, email, registration

I have set up the user registration form which requires email validation. However the code isn't able to generate an email
connection file:

```
$host="xxxx"; 
$dbname="xxxx";
$dbuser="xxxx";
$dbpassword="xxxx";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname); 
$website_url="http://www.xxxx/email_activation/";
$sender_email="xxxx@yahoo.com";
```

send_mail.php

```
function send_mail($to,$subject,$body)
{
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$from       = "from@yourwebsite.com";
$mail       = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(true);            // use SMTP
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication  
$mail->Host       = "tls://smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; // SMTP host  
$mail->Port       =  25;                    // set the SMTP port  
$mail->Username   = "xxxx@yahoo.com";  // SMTP  username   
$mail->Password   = "xxxx";  // SMTP password  
$mail->SetFrom($from, 'From Name');  
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,'From Name');  
$mail->Subject    = $subject;  
$mail->MsgHTML($body);  
$address = $to;  
$mail->AddAddress($address, $to);  
$mail->Send();  
}
```

Register file code:

```
$activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));  
include 'send_mail.php';  
$message = " To activate your account, please click on this link: \n\n ";  
$message .= $website_url . '/activate.php?email=' .urlencode($sender_email) .  
"&key=$activation";  
mail($email_address, 'Registeration Confirmation', $message, 'From:' .$sender_email);
```

Comment: You show a `function send_mail()`, but are using the standard php `mail()` function? I don't see how these 3 code samples are connected.

Comment: There is no error message, the only error is there is no confirmation email sent. I'm new to php, and I followed the steps listed in a blog. You're right, the function isn't called anywhere. Should I add the function after the include statement in the register file code?